# Taking a non-const reference of DenseBase<Derived> and fill it inside a function does not work

Tags: c++, eigen

I am writing a function to sort dense matrices or arrays in `Eigen` and also return the indices of the arrangement. The function is the following:

```
template<typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
typename Derived1::PlainObject sort(const DenseBase<Derived1> &x, DenseBase<Derived2> &indices)
{
    typename Derived1::PlainObject y = x.derived();
    typename Derived2::PlainObject z = indices.derived();

    z.resize(y.rows(), y.cols());
    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i)
        z(i) = i;

    std::sort(z.data(), z.data() + z.size(), [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return y(a) < y(b); });

    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i)
        y(i) = x((int) z(i));

    return y;
}
```

Now I want to call this function in some piece of code in the following manner:

```
const ArrayXXd x = ArrayXXd::Random(5, 5);
ArrayXXi indices;
const ArrayXXd xsort = sort(x, indices);
```

`x` is sorted correctly but I expected the `indices` matrix/array to hold the indices of the sorting process, but it is empty :|

What happens here? In the first function `z` (which is the underlying derived type of `indices`) is correctly allocated and filled, why after the function ends `indices` is empty?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see any code in the function that modifies `indices`, so why do you believe that `indices` should have changed?

Comment: Well, I thought that calling `derived` on `indices` it would return a reference (and indeed it does) to directly modify the object underlying `indices`. But I stored the output of `derived` as a copy not as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `z` to be a reference to `indices.derived()`, instead of a copy:

```
typename Derived2::PlainObject & z = indices.derived();
```

Make sure that `derived()` returns a reference as well.